# Compile CoffeeScript files on Node.js start with connect-assets

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, package

If I have `!= js('engagement')` in my `.jade` file, and that CoffeeScript file will compile into a `.js` file on page load and I can then access to the `.js` file directly.

But I **cannot start my Node.js server** and go directly to the `.js` file with `/js/engagement.js` in the url.

Is there some simple code that I suppose to put in my `app.js` to get the package **"connect-assets"** working different for compiling this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I call this specific problem "priming"; you want to use these files without referencing them in any views.  It's especially problematic with architectures involving [requireJS](http://requirejs.org) on the front end.

I've created a module called `connect-assets-jsprimer` that will prime all your coffeescript files on app startup so that they are available.  In essence, it just calls the connect-assets  `js("")` function on all the files in you assets/js folder (recursively).

Install with:

```
npm install connect-assets-jsprimer
```

Usage (in your server.js or whatever)

```
var assets = require('connect-assets');
var jsPrimer = require('connect-assets-jsprimer');

// Snip ...

app.use(assets());
jsPrimer(assets);

// Optionally, you can pass in a log function to see progress
// jsPrimer(assets, console.log);
```

After this, you should be able to request your javascript files straight away without rendering any views.

Source is up on github at [connect-assets-jsprimer](http://jgable.github.com/connect-assets-jsprimer)